# MySQL: Update a view fails on MySQL 5.7 but works on 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

This query fails on MySQL 5.7

```
UPDATE `view_alm` SET `cantidad_de_producto`='3' WHERE `id_producto`='43' LIMIT 1;
```

The same query works on MySQL 5.5 and 5.6. It is important to emphasize that "view_alm" is a view table.

The result of query on MySQL 5.7 is "**error: The target table view_alm of the UPDATE is not updatable**".

I read the section called "Updatable and Insertable Views" on documentation of MySQL: [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html)

I also check some parameters on my two testing enviroments (one enviroment is MySQL 5.7 and the other is MySQL 5.5).

- The query "SHOW VARIABLES;" return in both cases "updatable_views_with_limit                        | YES".
- On "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS" the flag "IS_UPDATABLE" is set to "YES" in both cases.

This is the view:

```
select `P`.`id_producto` AS `id_producto`,`P`.`id_cliente` AS `id_cliente`,`P`.`id_producto_definicion` AS `id_producto_definicion`,`P`.`caducidad` AS `caducidad`,`P`.`lote` AS `lote`,`P`.`cantidad_de_producto` AS `cantidad_de_producto`,`P`.`referencia_de_producto` AS `referencia_de_producto`,`P`.`id_tipo_stock` AS `id_tipo_stock`,`TS`.`nombre_stock` AS `nombre_stock`,`B`.`id_bulto` AS `id_bulto`,`BDEF`.`nombre` AS `nombre_bulto`,`C`.`id_contenedor` AS `id_contenedor`,`CDEF`.`nombre` AS `nombre_contenedor`,`U`.`id_ubicacion` AS `id_ubicacion`,`UDEF`.`codigo_de_ubicacion` AS `codigo_de_ubicacion` from ((((((((`productos` `P` left join `productos_definiciones` `PDEF` on((`P`.`id_producto_definicion` = `PDEF`.`id_producto_definicion`))) left join `bultos` `B` on((`B`.`id_bulto` = `P`.`bulto`))) left join `bultos_definiciones` `BDEF` on((`B`.`id_bulto_definicion` = `BDEF`.`id_bulto_definicion`))) left join `contenedores` `C` on((`B`.`contenedor` = `C`.`id_contenedor`))) left join `contenedores_definiciones` `CDEF` on((`C`.`id_contenedor_definicion` = `CDEF`.`id_contenedor_definicion`))) left join `ubicaciones` `U` on((`C`.`ubicacion` = `U`.`id_ubicacion`))) left join `ubicaciones_definiciones` `UDEF` on((`U`.`id_ubicacion_definicion` = `UDEF`.`id_ubicacion_definicion`))) left join `tipo_stock` `TS` on((`P`.`id_tipo_stock` = `TS`.`id_tipo_stock`))) order by `P`.`caducidad`
```

Can anyone give me any clues?

Comment: Since you read the documentation, you might have read that this flag can be unreliable depending on the actual view code. So you will have to add the actual view code. Also: does just selecting from your view return the correct row you want to update?

Comment: I just updated the question with code of view.

Comment: More information: this query works fine "SELECT * FROM `view_alm` WHERE `id_producto`='43' LIMIT 1;"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed!

Changed this:

```
UPDATE `view_alm` SET `cantidad_de_producto`='3' WHERE `id_producto`='43' LIMIT 1;
```

for:

```
UPDATE `productos` SET `cantidad_de_producto`='3' WHERE `id_producto`='43' LIMIT 1;
```

The fields "cantidad_de_producto" and "id_producto" are from the table "productos". In this case, solution is modify data on table "productos" instead of "view_alm".

Comment: Doesn't address the core issue.